# Count distinct multiple columns for each another column

Tags: mysql, count

Let’s have a table "pairs" with 3 columns, like this:
pairs(person, item1, item2)

```
1, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 1, 2
2, 2, 1
2, 2, 1
```

How to get a number of unique pairs of item1-item2 for each person? Like this:
Person , pair_num

```
1, 2
2, 1
```

All I can think out is :
select person, count(*) from (
select distinct person, item1, item2
from pairs
)
group by person;

But is there any solution without a subquery?

Comment: In RDBMS land, a table without a PRIMARY KEY isn't really  a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count(distinct)` can take multiple arguments:

```
select person, count(distinct item1, item2) as numpairs
from pairs
group by person;
```

If you want (1,2) to be the same as (2,1), then use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select person, count(distinct least(item1, item2), greatest(item1, item2)) as numpairs
from pairs
group by person;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person, (item1 + item2) AS pair FROM pairs GROUP BY person;
```